# What causes this partition discrepancy between GParted and Disk Management?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-management

Here's a screenshot of my partition layout as seen by GParted:

[image: GParted]

There are three primary partitions and an extended partition (it's a MBR disk) that contains two logical disks, some unallocated space and one more logical disk.

Now, here's the same disk as seen by Windows:

[image: Disk Management]

Four primary partitions, then an extended partition containing one logical disk and unallocated space, then one more primary partition. That's 6 top-level partitions, while MBR allows only four.

**What causes this anomaly? How can I diagnose it? How can I fix it?**

Here's `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7a675f3e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  83888127  83886080    40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        83888128  92276735   8388608     4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3  *     92276736 251660287 159383552    76G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       251660288 625141759 373481472 178,1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       251662336 293605375  41943040    20G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       293607424 377493503  83886080    40G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       608364544 625141759  16777216     8G 83 Linux
```

Additional information:

- All partitions except `sda6` were created under Linux before Windows was installed. `sda6` (the sole logical disk detected by Windows) was created later using Disk Management. It already displayed all partitions as primary prior to that.
- When I installed Windows to `sda3`, `sda5` disappeared from the partition table. It wasn't wiped, when I recreated it without formatting the data was still there. Then I installed Windows on `sda3` again and `sda5` disappeared, just like before.
- Windows detects this disk as MBR.
- It's Windows 7 Professional 32-bit with all updates installed.